# より in 実家より、またご連絡いたします

Tags: particle-より

I knew about より and its comparative function but it seemed not suitable for this sentence:

> 実家より、またご連絡いたします。

What's the meaning of "実家より" in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 「実家{じっか}より、またご連絡{れんらく}いたします。」

「より」, in this context, means the same thing as 「から」("***from***").  「より」 is more formal than 「から」.

> "I will contact you again from my parents' home."

The official Japanese title of the James Bond film ['**From** Russia with Love'](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/007_%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A%E6%84%9B%E3%82%92%E3%81%93%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6) is 「007 ロシア**より**愛をこめて」.  It would sound too light and casual to use 「から」there.

Comment: Can you please tell me just for my practicing, how Japanese pronouce 007 in the title of this James Bond movie? Maybe ゼロゼロセフン [zero-zero-sefun]?