# より vs から to mean "from"

Tags: particles

Suppose person A writes a letter to someone. I think the standard way for A to sign it off would be 「Aより」.

Would it still be correct if I replaced より with から?
Is there any difference in formality and context when it comes to choosing between から and より to mean "from"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57905/about-%e3%82%88%e3%82%8a-function/57906#57906

Comment: @l'électeur Thank you for the link; that indeed answers the second part of my question. I can surmise from it that it would be perfectly acceptable to replace より with から when signing the letter if the recipient is a close acquaintance. Is that right?