# Yori in letters

Tags: particle-より

[image]

In the picture, it is signed "Yaeka" (this is from Kumichou Musume to Sewagakari) who is the author of the letter.  The translation says "Love, Yaeka" but I'm pretty sure Yori doesn't mean love, and I can't find any part of the letter that has that meaning, so I think it is a cultural translation.

How is Yori being used where it says Yaeka yori?

Is Yori typically used in letters?

Comment: The "duplicate" answer does not discuss the same より.

Comment: I don't really understand the answer to that question I was marked as a duplicate for either.

Comment: Oops, sorry I voted to close with a wrong one. Meaningwise, it is a より same as https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57905/45489.

Answer (score 4):

へ・より are *the* particles for addressee/addresser in letters. So they mean *to/from* respectively.

Note that the above only applies to the usage at the beginning/end of letters. In normal sentences に/から are more frequently used.

- Ａさんに(へ)メールを出した。 *I wrote an email to A*
- Ａさんから手紙をもらった。*I received a letter from A*. I think より is a bit odd here.
- 本部より打電 *Telegram from the HQ!*

へ/より sounds generally strained if used in speech.